# Как отделить номер захватываемой группы от цифры?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пример:

```
"abcdefghijklm".replace(/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)/, "$11")
```

Получается `k`.

Что надо сделать, чтобы получить конкатенацию первой группы и цифры 1, т. е. `a1`?

Comment: А `..."$1") + "1"` - не вариант?

Comment: Это через функцию можно сделать (вместо строки замены)

Comment: Так: `..., "$1\x011")` вроде работает, или так `$1\x001` - т.е. между `$1` и нашей `1` вставляем невидимый символ

Comment: @BOPOH, нет. Выведи length того, что получится после `"$1\x011"` - там 3 символа `a`, `\0x01` и `1` - очевидно, что средний лишний.

Comment: Ну так я и написал - "вставляем невидимый символ" ) Если это нужно только пользователю показать, то он скорее всего не будет против лишних символов о которых не знает

Comment: @installero, у незахватываемых групп номеров нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Забавно. Не нашел ответа в документации, но нашел его методом научного тыка.
Из документации мне стало известно, что JavaScript поддерживает от 0 до 99 сохраняющих групп.
Когда я наобум попробовал

```
"abcdefghijklm".replace(/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)/, "$011")
```

то увидел

```
a1
```

То есть встретив `$01`, `$02` ... `$09` JavaScript понимает их как группы `$1`, `$2` ... `$9`.

Comment: Оригинально. Не знал, что число групп ограничено. Но пихать больше сотни групп в регулярку, пожалуй, не слишком хорошая идея.

Comment: Проверил: `Array(111).join("a").replace(RegExp(Array(111).join("(.)")), "$011")` даёт `a1`, а в таком варианте `Array(111).join("a").replace(RegExp(Array(111).join("(.)")), function() { return arguments.length })` функция честно получает свои 113 параметров (вхождение + 110 групп + индекс + строка).

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос - вам нужен `$'1` или `` $`1 ``

```
"abcdefghijklm".replace(/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)/, "$1$'1")
```

И если кому будет интересно:

```
"$1$$1" => "a$1"
"$&" => "abcdefghijklm"
```

Comment: тестировал в хроме и огнелисе

Comment: У этих символов своё значение есть, это в конкретном случае совпало, что там строки пустые. Из `"abcdefghijklmnk".replace(/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(g)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)/, "$11")` так уже не получится `ab1k`.

Comment: Упс. Тогда извините

Answer (score 2):

Группы, кстати, можно делать незахватываемыми

```
"abcdefghijklm".replace(/(.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)(?:.)/, '$11')
=> a1
```

Comment: Я знаю, но всё равно держи плюсик :)

Comment: Мне кажется, что ТС привел абстрактный пример, далекий от реального выражения, но минимально демонстрирующий проблему, поэтому несохранение групп это уход от абстракции.

Answer (score 0):

Есть в юникоде символы с кодами uFF10-uFF19 подозрительно похожие на цифры 0-9. Можно вместо цифры воспользоваться таким кодом.

```
"abcdefghijklm".replace(/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)/, "$1\uFF11")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5do1vpf/