# Как отделить группу от цифр?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как при замене по регулярке в строке подстановки после группы `$1` написать нечто, начинающееся с цифры, чтобы оно не стало частью номера группы?

---

Например, здесь два подряд идущих одинаковых символа заменяется на этот символ, пробел и цифру 2: https://ideone.com/ccxPbK

```
Regex.Replace("abbcccdddd", @"(.)\1", "$1 2") // ab 2c 2cd 2d 2
```

Но если попытаться сделать то же самое без пробела, то получается 12я группа и результат совсем не тот, какой хотелось бы: https://ideone.com/K2D1TF

```
Regex.Replace("abbcccdddd", @"(.)\1", "$12") // a$12$12c$12$12
```

PS: Интересует не конкретно эта задача, а проблема в целом.

Comment: Возможно, `"$1" + "2"` сработает? PS А, нет, не работает.

Comment: @AK, с чего бы, если результат - всё равно строка? о_О

Comment: Именованные группы?

Comment: Кстати, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446315/178988 - аналогичный вопрос для js.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, возможно. А что, без них никак? :(

Comment: Возможно, но зачем? Не сильно понял сути вопроса, но вот так у меня работает: `Regex.Replace("abbcccdddd", @"(?'s'.)\1", "${s}2")`

Comment: Не нужны именованные группы, `Regex.Replace("abbcccdddd", @"(.)\1", "${1}2")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, давай в ответы)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно в строковом шаблоне замены номер группы заключить в фигурные скобки:

```
Regex.Replace("abbcccdddd", @"(.)\1", "${1}2")
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%5C1&i=abbcccdddd&r=%24%7B1%7D2).

Именованные группы тоже можно использовать для этих целей:

```
Regex.Replace("abbcccdddd", @"(?<name>.)\k<name>", "${name}2")
```

См. [ещё одно демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cname%3E.%29%5Ck%3Cname%3E&i=abbcccdddd&r=%24%7Bname%7D2).

Если с совпадением нужно произвести какие-нибудь дополнительные операции, то можно воспользоваться

```
Regex.Replace("abbcccdddd", @"(.)\1", m => $"{m.Groups[1].Value}2")
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/KZDInl - первый вариант на ideone.

Comment: А группы всё-таки "именованные".